# Symfony 2 inconsistency in logout route: logout redirect to login?

Tags: symfony

I'd like to solve this inconsistency in my Symfony 2 application: when user is **not** authenticated path `/app/logout` redirects to `/app/login`. Instead, user not authenticated should view an error page (maybe 403).

Here is the security configuration. The `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` seems mandatory, as an user can do logout only if it's previously authenticated fully:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/app/login,  roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/app/logout, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

And the logout action of my `AccessController`:

```
/**
 * @Extra\Route("logout")
 * @Extra\Template
 */
public function logoutAction()
{
    // Set the token to null and invalidate the session
    $this->getSecurityContext()->setToken(null);
    $this->getSession()->invalidate();

    // Redirect url and seconds (window.location)
    $seconds  = 5;
    $redirect = $this->getRouter()->generate('access_login');

    return array('seconds' => $seconds, 'redirect' => $redirect);
}
```

One solution would be removing the route `/app/logout` from access control and then throwing an exception if user it's not fully authenticated:

```
if(false === $this->getSecurityContext()->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'))
    throw new AccessDeniedException();
```

But this way `/app/logout` would be accessible even from not authenticated users! Anyone knows a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the logout path from `access_control`. Nothing bad is going to happen if a not authenticated user goes to the logout page — it's safe. Don't overengineer this stuff. ;)

BTW, why aren't you using the Symfony's built-in logout controller? You could create a logout handler to put your custom code in it instead of reinventing the wheel by handling all the logout stuff yourself.

Comment: What would be the difference in using logout handler instead of a custom controller action?

Comment: It's more idiomatic to Symfony. Use built-in solutions whenever they solve your problems; resort to your custom code only when there is no satisfying solution available. What if the logout logic changes in a future version of Symfony? You'll have to watch for that and update your code. If you use the built-in stuff, you don't have to bother.